# How to create a historical dataframe with calculated data?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dataframe that has historical values with the values I calculated with.

I have df1 as below:

```
df1:
      A    B
0   2.0  3.0`
1   4.0  6.0
2   6.0  9.0
```

I calculated mean of df1 as below:

```
m1 = df1.mean(axis=0)

m1:
A  4.0
B  6.0
```

'm1' is mean of entire data series from 0 to 2 (index).

Instead of getting m1, what I want is to get a dataframe of mean for historical period. For example, I want to get mean value of every two periods (two consecutive indexes) and create them as a dataframe. The output I want is as below:

```
# I want mean of two consecutive periods of each column as below.

df2:
     A     B
0  3.0   4.5
1  5.0   7.5
```

Can you help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), which provides rolling window calculations for however large a window you want. From your example, it seems like you want a window size of 2 (calculate the mean of 2 rows at a time):

```
df1.rolling(2).mean()

     A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1  3.0  4.5
2  5.0  7.5
```

The only issue is that it gives you `NaN` for your first index, because there is nothing to calculate on the first row. You could just ignore this, but if you want to get rid of it, you can slice out that row:

```
df1.rolling(2).mean().iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)

     A    B
0  3.0  4.5
1  5.0  7.5
```

Comment: Hi Sacul, Thank you. Can I use 'rolling()' to other calculation as well? For example, you helped me about the 'slopes'. Can I use rolling() to 'df.apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(df.index, x, 1)[0])'?

Comment: You can apply other calculations on `rolling()`, but as far as the one I gave you the other day, I'm not sure what you'd want to be calculating with it. As is, you cannot apply that function, it would have to be modified according to what you want to achieve with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using moving window 2 , you can consider `shift`

```
(df.add(df.shift())/2).dropna()
Out[25]: 
     A    B
1  3.0  4.5
2  5.0  7.5
```

Comment: @Mike if you like our solutions , you can upvote for that

Comment: @Mike You have received two good answers here. Please consider accepting one of them as a formal answer to your question by clicking the checkmark below the answer score. Now that you've gained more than 15 rep points, you also have the opportunity to upvote one or both of them.